# Ethernet switch link issues - when connecting to sibling (RTL8305NB)

Tags: ethernet

I have built a PCB to **test an Ethernet Switch IC** (RTL8305NB-VB-CG). When connecting devices to the switch (like my laptop, or another 'brand' switch), **it works great**. Link is stable and I get close to 100mbit/s, which is what I expect.

However, when connecting my test switch to another one of my test switch boards (exact same board), the **link state goes on and off every ~2 seconds**. On rare occasion I have seen it stabilize and keep the link up, but mostly it will keep toggling the link state. This happens both when connecting on ports 1 and 3 (regular RJ45 jack with magnetics) as well as port 4 (magnetics separate from connector/cabling).

Any idea on how I can fix this?

The schematic for the RTL8305 part of my board can be found here:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/i1fx9oegit73ld06bflf8/Ethernet_test_PCB_1.pdf?rlkey=wufifuopn4a33ul6zpn312mkr&dl=1